# Tournaments: how to determine rankings if multiple players are knocked out in the same hand?

Tags: rules, tournament

Imagine this Scenario:

We have a Sit N Go tournament with 10 people, and top 5 win money.

In the **very first** hand, all 10 players go all in (with the same amount of chips obviously), and 1 player wins.

How are rankings 2-10 determined? what happens to the prize money for places 2-5?

Comment: My guess is that the prize money for places 2 to 5 are evenly distributed between the knocked out players, but I haven't find the confirmation anywhere.

Comment: see related post http://poker.stackexchange.com/questions/4232/what-determines-who-finishes-in-a-paid-position-after-hand-for-hand-play

Comment: I just want to point out that if would be *very* sub-optimal for all 10 people to go all in on the first hand.  Even if the 10th (last) person to act had pocket aces, it would be sub-optimal (and likely -EV) play to call in this position: with 9 players already all in, you are almost virtually guaranteed to cash, very likely at a minimum in 2nd place, if you simply fold.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Since everyone started the hand with the same chip count and the tournament pays 5 places, the total prize pool for places 2 through 5 should be combined and then divided equally among the 9 people eliminated in the hand. It doesn't matter whose hands were better than others among the losers of the hand. The only relevant fact is the chip counts at the start of the hand.

Just poking around, I see that [Full Tilt's tournament rules](http://www.fulltilt.com/poker/tournaments/rules) page describes this situation in rule #24.

> If two or more players are eliminated on the same hand, the player
>   with more chips at the beginning of the hand is placed higher. If
>   players started the hands with an identical amount of chips, both
>   players tie for that rank, and any prizes due to those players will be
>   equally distributed between them.